# Creating static states in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, static, state

I'm using ReactJS. I have a file global.js containing all the global settings (Colors, Font, etc). Its code looks something like

```
import React from 'react';

export default class GlobalVariables extends React.Component{     
  static variable1 = value1;
  static variable2 = value2;
  //And so on...  
};
```

In my components, I use these in the following way

```
import GlobalVariables from 'filePath/GlobalVariables.js';

//And somewhere inside the component, the value is assigned as:
myComponentValue = GlobalVariables.variable1;
```

Trouble starts when I need to alter these values (For instance, lets say I need to apply theming and decide to change the color parameters).

I altered the values in the component using

```
GlobalVariables.variable1 = newValue;
```

Since these variables aren't states, components are not re-rendered until the page is refreshed. Also, some components that load later take the new value leaving the page looking messy.

I tried using states, but each instance of a class can have different states. So modifying the state in one instance will not effect the others.

I'm looking for something static (since its being imported by multiple parent components) as well as having a state (so that the changes take immediate effect)

Comment: Have to tried Context API?

Comment: @fayeed It worked. Wasn't aware of it. Thanks!